# Tiny flash in safari

Tags: javascript, flash, safari

We have a flash file that in every other browser displays at its correct size (which is something like 1600px) however, in safari it appears tiny.  We have also noticed that sometimes when the flash file is not cached it appears at normal size, then after a soft refresh the flash goes tiny again.

We are using mootools to include the flash, but I've also tried just using flash's HTML/Javascript with the publish function, we still have the same problem with it being tiny in safari.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance resizing the size of the flash movie dynamically at all (listening for Event.RESIZE or setting the stage size when the Flash movie loads)? There's a number of known issue in a certain browsers (safari being one) where certain events do not fire when the flash object is cached and "reloaded". Check the following link. My workaround has always been to pass size parameters to the flash object to use on load.

http://pixelfumes.blogspot.com/2007/07/ie6-as3-preloader-events-failing.html

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. I found that once I removed the html table surrounding the flash embed code Safari rendered the Flash movie at the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have changed the size in the HTML in one place, but not the other.
Note: in the code, you need it in 2 places: OBJECT and EMBED.

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
    WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="82%">

    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="filename.swf"> 
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> 
    <PARAM NAME=salign VALUE=T> 
    <PARAM NAME=devicefont VALUE=true> 
    <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#fffff7>

    <EMBED src="filename.swf" quality=high salign=T devicefont=true bgcolor=#fffff7 WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="82%   
        TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```